# Is there another way I can write an if that I use to set a javascript value?

Tags: javascript

I am using this but it does not look so clear:

```
if (!app.config.admin.examStatusId) {
  app.config.admin.examStatusId = exam.examStatus.dataPlus[0].id; 
}
```

Is there another more clear way that I could write this without using an if ?

Comment: You could write it as `app.config.admin.examStatusId = app.config.admin.examStatusId | exam.examStatus.dataPlus[0].id;` but most of the clarity problem comes from the fact you change a deep property. In a clearly designed program, you'd probably have in your scope a variable whose value would be `app.config.admin`.

Comment: That's as clear as it get's too me ?

Comment: Move the body of the `if` to the next line and it will look just fine.

Comment: @adeneo what do you think should be done with this question ?

Comment: @dystroy You are missing one more `|` ;)

Comment: @thefourtheye right... and I'm missing a few coffees too... OP, it' `||`, not `|`

Comment: @dystroy - Can you put this in as an answer. Your suggestion looks good to me.

Comment: @dystroy - question seems fine, just saying an if statement is as clear and readable as it gets. Using OR is fine as well, but not sure if it's any clearer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write it as

```
app.config.admin.examStatusId = app.config.admin.examStatusId || exam.examStatus.dataPlus[0].id;
```

but your `if` is fine too. Most of the clarity problem comes from the fact you change a deep property : In a clearly designed program, you'd probably have in your scope a variable whose value would be `app.config.admin`. It's rare to have to touch distant submodules in a program.

Answer (score 0):

```
!app.config.admin.examStatusId ? app.config.admin.examStatusId = exam.examStatus.dataPlus[0].id : /*something else if it is false*/
```

This is a shorthand method for if/else called ternary logic. You can read a little more about it here: http://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
app.config.admin.examStatusId = app.config.admin.examStatusId || exam.examStatus.dataPlus[0].id;
```